# Accessing list in dictionary of django template

Tags: python, django, templatetag

Hi I have a Django template tag to get an rss feed. It is quite simple and uses feedparser to place the decoded result in the context. 
IE

```
context[self.var_name] = feedparser.parse(self.url)
```

For a particular url 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/england/oxford/rss.xml'
The first entry printed from feedparser has an entry like this
(I have removed other keys to keep this post short).

```
{'media_thumbnail': [{'url': u'_67862157_67862150.jpg', 'width': u'66', 'height': u'49'}, {'url': u'67862000/jpg/_67862158_67862150.jpg', 'width': u'144', 'height': u'81'}]}
```

However, in my template tag test the element 'media_thumbnail' is changed so the list is empty.

My test case

```
class GetRssTagTest(TestCase):

    def test_request(self):
        t = Template('{% load rss_parser %}}{% get_rss "feed.xml" as rss %}{{rss.entries.0}}')
        c = Context({})
        print t.render(c)
```

returns

```
{media_thumbnail&#39;: u&#39;&#39;}
```

(Again have removed other fields)

I can't understand why is element has been removed ? There are other lists in that dictionary that have been left.

Is there some kind of key/size limit to what can be passed to a context variable ?

I know I could make a tag custom and do this in Python but I would rather keep the tag generic for use with other feeds.

Thanks

Comment: Not that this makes a difference, but `{% load rss_parser %}}` has a trailing `}`. Also `{media_thumbnail&#39;: u&#39;&#39;}` looks incorrect to me - It should have been `{&#39;media_thumbnail&#39;: u&#39;&#39;}` . I m guessing there is a typo somewhere

Comment: That could be a copy/paste/edit issue when writing the question.